# Angular renderer setStyle will not apply linear-gradient

Tags: css, angular, angular-renderer2

Angular's renderer2 will not apply linear-gradient CSS. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.setStyle(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      "background",
      "linear-gradient(rgba(253,92,99,1), rgba(144,255,0,1) 30%);" 
      // "red" // works, so does this rule in CSS
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-renderer-gradient?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) repro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben,

last semicolon in gradient rule produces an error:
this way it works:

```
    this.renderer.setStyle(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      "background",
      "linear-gradient(rgba(253,92,99,1), rgba(144,255,0,1) 30%)" //no semicolon in the end
    );
```